# Nginx access application without port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have application running with nginx on:

`http://10.20.0.77:8080`

At the end I want to access application via lets say http://xyz.zyx.de in my Network. The IT administrator said, that before he will set up the configuration on the DNS Server, I first need to setup reverse proxy on my application server.

So therefore, I am trying to achieve that, my application appears when I just request for:

`http://10.20.0.77`

How can I do that in nginx?

My current configuration is:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  10.20.0.77;
    root         /opt/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
     include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass  http://10.20.0.77:8080/#/;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header  Host  $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Comment: This configuration is impossible, nginx would be proxying to itself.

Comment: You should try `proxy_pass http://10.20.0.77:8080` and leave out the rest of the line.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, that wouldn't change the fact that this config is trying to have nginx listening on the same address and port as the application.  Either nginx or the application will not start, depending on who's first.

Comment: That is true too, but my point was that the `/#/` part can cause issues, because it contains fragment separator, which is a client-side construct.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx needs to listen on port 80, which is the default for http if you don't specify a port.  As in:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xyz.zyx.de;
```

Comment: So what would be a correct configuration?

Comment: OK, Thanks, but after doing the change u suggested. When I enter `10.20.0.77` I get directed to the nginx application server welcome page. But should not I be directed to my applications index.html instead?

Comment: No you shouldn't.  My solution tried to make "http: //xyz.zyx.de/" work.

Comment: Alright, thanks I will give it a try once the IT Admin is available

Comment: Until the DNS has been configured, you can modifiy the hosts file on the system where you want to test it, and add "10.20.0.77  xyz.zyx.de" to that file.  Restart your browser and try to visit "h t t p : / / xyz.zyx.de".  Viel Glück!